# Formatting dates with R

Tags: r, date, time, format

I need to format a date variable with R. I get the current date with a simple date().

```
    today <- date()
    today
  > "Mon Oct 10 1:00 2016"
```

I need to format this 'today' variable into a string with a specific format. below is an example of what the string should look like.

```
    string <- ”10/10/2016 1:00 PM EDT"
    string
  > ”10/10/2016 1:00 PM EDT"
```

So the question is how do you format a character string that looks like "Mon Oct 10 1:00 2016" into ”10/10/2016 1:00 PM EDT".

I've tried working with strptime() and as.Date() functions but cannot figure out how to convert this string into a formatted date. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

```
strftime(strptime(date(),
 format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y"),
 format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p %Z")
```

See `??strptime`.